How to combine multiple Collections (Queue or List) element by element?
I have 3 queues of records (of idential size and datetime order) and want to combine them record by record.
It is similar to below:
record BuyOrder(String date, String product, double buyPx) {};
record SellOrder(String date, double sellPx) {};
record Transaction(String date, double commission, int volume) {};
record Combined(BuyOrder b, SellOrder s, Transaction t);
Queue<BuyOrder> buys = new LinkedList<>();
Queue<SellOrder> sells = new Linkedlist<>();
Queue<Transaction> transactions = new LinkedList<>();
Queue<Combined> combined = new LinkedList<>();

The combined queue should be [date, product, buyPx, sellPx, commission, volume], [date, product, buyPx, sellPx, commission, volume], ... created using the 3 queue elements. How can I do this?
I am using a loop but believe that there gotta be a more efficient and simpler way. Such as using stream()?
@assert (buys.size() == sells.size() && sells.size() == transactions.size());
for (BuyOrder buy: buys) {
  SellOrder sell = sells.poll(); //remove the head
  Transaction transaction = transactions.poll();
  combined.add(new Combined(buy, sell, transaction);
)


This seems like a terrible design, why are you flattening everything into a raw Object[]? Create a new data type. Let it take a BuyOrder, SellOrder and Transaction. Use a Queue of that custom type. Don't use an Object[].

@ElliottFrisch that is trivial and is edited, but how can I combine/join those queues or arraylists one by one into the combined collection?

Make the constructor Combined(BuyOrder, SellOrder, Transaction). Pass it three fields. Use OOP and structure. Not destructuring.

Streams will definitely not help in this situation.

@ElliottFrisch that's right, makes sense to take the custom types. Post edited. My question is if there is a way to combine without using loop?

@LouisWasserman is there a better/cleaner way to do than the loop?

Definitely not.  You cannot meaningfully improve on the loop.

@LouisWasserman the loop looks lame..

I don't think it's an improvement, but I suppose you could do List<Combined> combined = buys.stream().map(buy -> new Combined(buy, sells.poll(), transactions.poll())).collect(Collectors.toList());

Assuming you have the Queue combined = new LinkedList<>();
buys.stream().map(buy -> new Combined(buy, sells.poll(), transactions.poll())).map(r -> combined.offerLast(r));

@ManikJain, that is a no-op and doesn't do anything.  It's also much harder to follow.  The best path forward is almost certainly to fix the bug in yourself that considers loops bad.

Not a big deal but if you are using record, you’re certainly not using [tag:java-8]…

No change needed
You asked:

is there a better/cleaner way to do than the loop?

No.
As discussed in the Comments, your for loop is good. The code is clear, easy to comprehend.
Use streams only where they enhance your code, or improve performance, not because they are "cool"/"not lame". A for loop neatly solves the problem at hand whereas using streams would be overkill.  Don’t bring a chainsaw solution to a whittling problem.

The only change I would make is to add same null-checks and data-validation to make sure that you do indeed have three matching elements across all three queues.
